# how to identify an dynamic array with boolean value properly?

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

This code is to find the prime number in a certain range. I used the algorithm of Eratosthenes. Seem the range of my dynamic array is wrong. because when I input 50, 49 is in the prime set, when I input 30, 25 is still in the prime set.

I've checked the for loop. there should have no problem.

```
void Eratosthenes(int n)
{
    bool* prime;
    prime = new bool[n+1];
    memset(prime, true, sizeof(prime));

    for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++)
    {
        if (prime[p] == true)
        {
            for (int i = p * p; i <= n; i += p)
                prime[i] = false;
        }
    }
    for (int p = 2; p <= n; p++)
        if (prime[p])
            cout << p << " ";
    delete[] prime;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "enter a interger " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    Eratosthenes(n);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(prime)` gives you the size of a pointer-to-bool, which (probably) doesn't match the size of your array.  Instead you should use [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) or just use `n+1` directly.

Comment: @ox5453 - `std::size()` does not work on a pointer either.

Comment: @Peter Good point.  Better to just use [`std::fill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) instead of `memset`; it's harder to get wrong.

Comment: Can we assume that you are a poor, benighted student and the glories that are [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool) are forbidden to you? `vector<bool>` is a bit of a performance hit (bunch of bit packing going on) , but you can easily initialize it to true or false and it'll take up much MUCH less memory than the array. Totally [Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) compliant and handles all of the memory management details like safe freeing of its backing array for you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want correct the number of elements which should be initialized:

```
memset(prime, true, sizeof(*prime)*(n+1));
```